Can you update a vue.js web app if you don't have the source code only the build files
There is a web app written in vue.js asp.net core and the only thing I can find is the build files in the IIS server.  Can this be updated or do I need the source files?
Opened project folders but cant make sense of it.  From what I can tell only the build files were uploaded to the web server.  There are no web config files or dependencies.  Is there any way to back track with these files or do I need to find the source code?

Yes,need source code

I don't think so
